# No exact match for RANGE query for a specific time

Tags: elasticsearch, range

## Question

Why does the Elasticsearch Range query not exact match with the time "2017-11-30T13:23:23.063657+11:00"? Kindly suggest if there is a mistake in the query or it is expected.

### Query

```
curl -XGET 'https://hostname/_search?pretty' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
    "query": {
        "range" : {
            "time" : {
                "gte": "2017-11-30T13:23:23.063657+11:00",
                "lte": "2017-11-30T13:23:23.063657+11:00"
            }
        }
    }
}
'
```

The expected only one data to match is below.

```
{
  "_index": "***",
  "_source": {
    "time": "2017-11-30T13:23:23.063657+11:00",
    "log_level": "INFO",
    "log_time": "2017-11-30 13:23:23,042"
  },
  "fields": {
    "time": [
      1512008603063
    ]
  }
}
```

### Result

However, it matched multiple records which is closer to the time.

```
"hits" : {
"total" : 11,
"max_score" : 1.0,
"hits" : [ {
  "_index" : "***",
  "_score" : 1.0,
  "_source" : {
    "time" : "2017-11-30T13:23:23.063612+11:00",
    "log_level" : "INFO",
    "log_time" : "2017-11-30 13:23:23,016"
  }
}, {
  "_index" : "core-apis-non-prod.97d5f1ee-a570-11e6-b038-02dc30517283.2017.11.30",
  "_score" : 1.0,
  "_source" : {
    "time" : "2017-11-30T13:23:23.063722+11:00",  
    "log_level" : "INFO",
    "log_time" : "2017-11-30 13:23:23,046"
  }
}
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elasticsearch uses Joda-Time for parsing dates. And your problem is that Joda-Time only stores date/time values down to the millisecond.

From the [docs](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/):

> The library internally uses a **millisecond** instant which is identical
>   to the JDK and similar to other common time representations. This
>   makes interoperability easy, and Joda-Time comes with out-of-the-box
>   JDK interoperability.

This means that the last 3 digits of the seconds are not taken into account when parsing the date.

`2017-11-30T13:23:23.063612+11:00`
`2017-11-30T13:23:23.063657+11:00`
`2017-11-30T13:23:23.063722+11:00`

Are all interpreted as:
`2017-11-30T13:23:23.063+11:00`

And the corresponding epoch time is `1512008603063` for all these values.

You can see this too by adding `explain` to the query like this:

```
{
    "query": {
        "range" : {
            "time" : {
                "gte": "2017-11-30T13:23:23.063657+11:00",
                "lte": "2017-11-30T13:23:23.063657+11:00"
            }
        }
    }, 
    "explain": true
}
```

That is basically the reason all those documents match your query.